Get UTC time in Apache Calcite SQL Query
I was trying out the Apache Calcite CSV example. Both CURRENT_TIME and LOCALTIME return time in the default time zone. Setting the 'timeZone=UTC' in the connection string didn't help, so I tried a variety of time zone references.
timeZone=gmt+00:00

timeZone=gmt+0:00

timeZone=utc

timeZone=gmt+00:00

even timeZone=America/Los_Angeles didn't change the session time zone.

looks like 'timeZone=UTC' connection string property is not working from the sqlline command line tool only. Using java code, I was able to get the UTC time with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP after passing 'timeZone=UTC' in JDBC connection string.
